# Critique: Best use of typographic space and negative space in this design?

Tags: typography, critique, white-space

Which design better uses space and is more appealing? I'm new to this community so please if this is the wrong place to ask this type of question direct me to the correct one. Thanks.

Design 1:

[image]

Design 2:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I much prefer **design 1**

It's got great use of white space and gives priority to the information. It also shows the shape of the map in a much more subtle way, 'there but not there'. 
In the second design the type seems a little squashed into a shape that takes priority, that  is by comparison to design 1 which is very fluid (literally) it seems to have a 'watery' flow to it as it is not confined, which I think further enforces your information, it's really nice!

It brings this image to mind;

[image]

Comment: I agree with Jenna - besides, the shape of Africa is "overused" in many ways. It is a characteristic shape, and there is no reason to make it massively intrusive.  It is easy enough to get it in the first example.

Comment: I have 1 more question, does the "THIS SHIRT" text obstruct the focus on the Africa shaped typography? Is it too much? Should it be included in the Africa shape typography instead?

Comment: Great question :) I would say that it's worth playing with and developing further. As it is I think you're right, it's a little distracting. It would be worth not only trying it in the Africa shape but also try your options with putting more space between 'this shirt' and the Africa shape, different fonts/arcs etc. Placing it in the shape is definitely a solution but you might find a better one experimenting :)